# Replacing \n in string with new lines in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, newline, string-formatting, cell-array

I'm trying to merge cell-array of strings delimiting each by new line to one string in Matlab.
Following method merges the strings, but the final string contains \n instead of new lines:

```
function str = toString(self)
    % some not important logic that creates cell array called strings
    % ...
    str = '';
    for i = 1 : 9               
        str = strcat(str, strings(i), '\n');
    end  
end
```

It returns: `'   111\n   111\n   111\n333666444555\n333666444555\n333666444555\n   222\n   222\n   222\n'`

When I add `str = sprintf(str);` before the end of the method, it returns Invalid format error. However when I write to Matlab command window `sprintf('   111\n   111\n   111\n333666444555\n333666444555\n333666444555\n   222\n   222\n   222\n');` it returns formatted string without any errors.

Anyone knows what could be a problem? Why it works in command window but doesn't in .m file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sprintf will loop over the elements or your cell array:

```
sprintf('%s\n', strings{:})
```

The problem with your loop is '\n' is a 2 element char array, but what you want is sprintf('\n')